# Append specific text from an SQLite database to multiple files

Tags: batch, database, sqlite

Here's what I have:

1. An SQLite database `main.db`
2. A set of 10,000x HTML files named `1.html`, `2.html`, `3.html` ... `10000.html`.

main.db has a table with 2 columns:

```
id    | name
1     | apple
2     | banana
3     | peach
...
10000 | orange
```

What I need is to insert text at the beginning of each html file the name referenced by its id, like this example:

Old 1.html:

```
<body>body content, text etc</body>
```

Desired 1.html:

```
<title>apple</title><body>body content, text etc</body>
```

What would be the preferred method for batch prepending?

Comment: "_append_" typically means "_add to the end_"... which is very simple (e.g: using redirection / `>>`). What you're asking for is actually "_prepend_", which is a little more dificult to achieve safely (i.e: you can't just use redirection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```bsh
# setup example database
sqlite3 main.db 'CREATE TABLE files(id INTEGER, name STRING)'
sqlite3 main.db 'INSERT INTO files(id, name) VALUES(1, "apple")'
sqlite3 main.db 'INSERT INTO files(id, name) VALUES(2, "banana")'
sqlite3 main.db 'INSERT INTO files(id, name) VALUES(3, "peach")'
sqlite3 main.db 'INSERT INTO files(id, name) VALUES(10000, "orange")'

# setup example input files
echo '<body>body content, text etc</body>' \
    | tee 1.html 2.html 3.html 10000.html \
    > /dev/null

# show original content of example files
tail *.html
```

```bsh
# fixup files "in-place"
while IFS='|' read id name; do
    filename="${id}.html"
    ( echo -n "<title>${name}</title>"; cat "${filename}" ) | sponge "${filename}"
done < <( sqlite3 main.db 'SELECT id,name FROM files' )
```

```bsh
# show final content of example files
tail *.html
```

Here we're using the following techniques:

- `sponge` - will read all of the input, before writing the data to the filename, given as an *argument* (**not** using shell redirection, as this truncates the file on open)
- `IFS='|' read id name` - by default, `sqlite3` will report one record per line, and delimit the columns using a pipe character (`|`) as the field separator.

  - This will have problems if you have newlines reported in a record's data.
  - Be aware that it *does not* escape pipe characters in the field value, so a record with `id=10000, name="ora|nge"` will be reported as `10000|ora|nge`.
  - In this situation, the first field (`10000`) is assigned to `${id}`, and all remaining fields (`ora` and `nge`) are assigned to `${name}`, with separators in tact (i.e: `ora|nge`), so you are okay... however you may be stung if you add fields or reorder them.

---

If you need to deal with things like newlines or pipe characters, then you might could:

- Iterate over IDs, calling the specific fields you're interested in one by one, one record at a time
- Work up a little python script or similar to do this more safely and likely faster:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('main.db')
for id, name in conn.execute('SELECT id,name FROM files'):
    with open(f'{id}.html', 'r+') as f:
        data = f.read()
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(f'<title>{name}</title>{data}')
```